# Copying fields data when checkbox is checked in multiple rows(Visualforce Page)

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component, javascript-controller

I have challenge I'm working on a visualforce page I want whenever the checkbox is checked I want to copy the values into input text fields in visualforce page.

So here I have multiple rows and corresponding to that I have checkboxes, Whenever I click a checkbox values should pass to input text fields.

For more understanding, I'm attaching the screenshot of challenge.

[image]

Comment: Hi, why do you want to do this in Javascript? Have you considered updating this in apex and rerender Unit Price and Quantity column?

Comment: That's my challenge, If you want to give a try you can

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This site is focused on helping you become a better programmer or admin by helping you overcome specific issues. To that end, it helps if you include the code/markup that you've developed so far. You should [edit] your question to include that.